# Why does SparkR (on databricks) not display summary function output when working with spark dataframes?

Tags: r, databricks, sparkr

On databricks, start with an R dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(n=1:1000)
```

Now the SparkR summary function provides nice output:

```
SparkR::summary(x)
```

```
   n
```

Min.   :   1.0
1st Qu.: 250.8
Median : 500.5
Mean   : 500.5
3rd Qu.: 750.2
Max.   :1000.0

Command took 0.02 seconds -- by *@* at 9/9/2020, 9:46:57 AM on aa_cluster_6w

Next I will convert the R dataframe to a spark dataframe:

```
y <- SparkR::createDataFrame(x=x)
```

I am able to confirm that object y is indeed, a Spark Dataframe:

```
class(y)
```

[1] "SparkDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"

Command took 0.01 seconds -- by *@* at 9/9/2020, 9:47:35 AM on aa_cluster_6w

Unfortunately, the SparkR library doesn't output the function results when I attempt to summarize it:

```
SparkR::summary(y)
```

SparkDataFrame[summary:string, n:string]

Command took 0.48 seconds -- by *@* at 9/9/2020, 9:47:16 AM on aa_cluster_6w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to answer the question myself while I was writing the question. So I might as well record the answer myself:

The Spark R summary function returns a dataframe, not text, so it must be converted to text. Two ways to do it as follows:

```
display(SparkR::summary(y))
```

or

```
SparkR::collect(SparkR::summary(y))
```

The display function prints Spark Dataframes as nice output in a databricks notebook.

The Spark R collect function pulls a spark dataframe into a local object in RAM on the driver of the active cluster. This operation is trivial for the tiny dataframe containing the statistical summary.